# How to manage multiple svn repo's inside one project?

Tags: svn

How does one manage multiple svn repo's during creation and deployment, without having a ton of grief?

My current folder structure more or less looks like

```
./                //svn url:mysvn.com/Project/
 lib              //svn url:mysvn.com/Project/Lib/
    ZEND          //svn url:mysvn.com/Zend
    Smarty        //svn url:mysvn.com/smarty
    InhouseLib1   //svn url:mysvn.com/InhouseLib1
    ProjectLib    //svn url:mysvn.com/Project/Lib/ProjectLib
 web              //svn url:mysvn.com/Project/Web
    js            //svn url:mysvn.com/Project/Web/js/
        jQuery    //svn url:mysvn.com/jQuery
        Stuff     //svn url:mysvn.com/Project/Web/js/Stuff        
    images        //svn url:mysvn.com/Project/Web/images
    etc..
```

Which causes an intricate dance when one has changed something, one wants to deploy something, or you are starting a new project and know you need a certain set of libs ( Eg `InHouseLib1` might be dependent on jQuery & Zend )

Is there any SVN magic that can somehow manage this complexity? ( preferably without restructuring the SVN repo )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it might be a job for [SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html).  In a nutshell, you can specify "links" to external repos from another repo.